# What number am I looking for?

Tags: rebus

Apparently  only posting the image is not allowed. So welcome to my 2nd puzzle here. I hope this one is a little tougher.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The number you're looking for is:

> **0.25**

The reasoning is:

> 0.5 is the sine of 30 degrees
>  That sine wave and thermometer are in a square, so 0.5 squared is 0.25

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic before why it is being squared. Sid's answer makes much more sense to me...

Comment: @Chris - the curve is that of a sine function, the thermometer shows 30 degrees, and [the value of sin(30°) = 0.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Special_values). Same reasoning as Sid upto this point, really.

Comment: Yeah. I'm just not sure why you then square it? There are no squares in the puzzle that I can make out. You just have a function and a value, you apply the function to the value and you get an answer which is what sid gave. I just don't understand where the square comes in.

Comment: See the square border around the sine wave and thermometer? They are enclosed in a square, i.e. they are "squared".

Comment: Ah! Despite how many times I looked at it my brain filtered that our because it was just the frame, obviously! :) Many thanks for taking the time to explain. :) And apologies also because I see you did write that too. I have no idea how I missed that. I blame the fact it is late here. :) Sorry!

Comment: I didn't see it at first either until I saw OP's comment beneath Sid's answer :-)

Comment: I'm glad at least someone recognized it as a thermometer. My drawing skills could indeed need some improvement :-)

Answer (score 3):

I sure hope there is something clever in this. But, the most obvious thing that comes to mind is:

> 1/2. Because the graph is of Sin x and the "test-tube" is filled upto 30 degrees. So, Sin 30 =1/2.

Comment: That is part of the answer but not the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Might be

> The sine of 30 degrees is 1/2 and  half of the vessel equals 70/2=35 degrees.